# Как сравнить String и Set<String>

Tags: java, строки, коллекции

Через `Scanner` ввожу любой текст, получается строка:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
String number = reader.nextLine();
```

Также имеется коллекция с результатами:

```
Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
```

Необходимо проверить, вводя текст, есть ли в коллекции вводимое значение.
При условии `if (number.equals(result))` - типы разные, поэтому не сравнивает.

Как можно сравнить?

Comment: Как сравнить корзину яблок с яблоком? Вопрос некорректный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для проверки наличия элемента в `Set`-е есть метод [contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains(java.lang.Object)):

```
if (result.contains(number))
```

Comment: Таким образом, любой введенный элемент будет true, вне зависимости что есть в коллекции.

Comment: @HektorFektor почему? Если в `result` хранятся только строки `"aaa"` и `"bbb"` и `number` равно `"ccc"`, то `contains` вернёт `false`.

Comment: Нашел ошибку, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @HektorFektor на здоровье. Если ответ вас устраивает, не забудьте отметить его как подходящий (галочка слева от ответа).